# Getting started with GearVRf

Tags: java, android, gear-vr

I'm trying to set up for development of app on the gearVR.

I want to use gearvrf as I think it will allow me to easily use the Java code I have already written for a cardboard app. However, I cannot get the sample applications to build.

I am following the instructions here:
https://resources.samsungdevelopers.com/Gear_VR/020_GearVR_Framework_Project/020_Get_Started

But when I build any of the sample applications, I get:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: :backend_daydream-debug:
Error:Failed to resolve: :framework-debug:
Error:Failed to resolve: :backend_oculus-debug:
```

and on the build log

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find :framework-debug:.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.aar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com//framework-debug//framework-debug-.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com//framework-debug//framework-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf-Demos/gearvrf-libs/framework-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf-Demos/gearvrf-libs/framework-debug.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework/build/outputs/aar/framework-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework/build/outputs/aar/framework-debug.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//framework-debug//framework-debug-.aar
 Required by:
     gvr-tutorial-lesson2:app:unspecified
> Could not find :backend_oculus-debug:.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.aar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf-Demos/gearvrf-libs/backend_oculus-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf-Demos/gearvrf-libs/backend_oculus-debug.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework/build/outputs/aar/backend_oculus-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework/build/outputs/aar/backend_oculus-debug.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//backend_oculus-debug//backend_oculus-debug-.aar
 Required by:
     gvr-tutorial-lesson2:app:unspecified
> Could not find :backend_daydream-debug:.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.aar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf-Demos/gearvrf-libs/backend_daydream-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf-Demos/gearvrf-libs/backend_daydream-debug.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework/build/outputs/aar/backend_daydream-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/dev/GearVRf/GVRf/Framework/framework/build/outputs/aar/backend_daydream-debug.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.aar
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.pom
     file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//backend_daydream-debug//backend_daydream-debug-.aar
 Required by:
     gvr-tutorial-lesson2:app:unspecified
```

How do you get sample applications to work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the library files ( aar ) and copy them in

*gearvrf-libs* directory if you are using demos from https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos

In your project you can put the library files in a *libs* directory and reference them in gradle file